# On the cellularity of the $G_\delta$-topology

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Given a topological space $X$, let $X_\delta$ be the topology on $X$ generated by the $G_\delta$ subsets of $X$. Let $c(X)$ be the cellularity of $X$, that is, the supremum of cardinalities of families of pairwise disjoint non-empty open subsets $X$. Thus $X$ is ccc if and only if $c(X)=\aleph_0$.

In 1972 Juhász proved:

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then $c(X_\delta) \leq 2^{c(X)}$.

Compactness can actually be replaced with pseudocompactness+regularity in Juhász's result.

Some form of compactness is essential in Juhász's theorem. For every cardinal $\kappa$ there is a (regular) ccc space $X$ such that $c(X_\delta) > \kappa$; some examples of such a space can be found in this other [Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130525/on-the-cardinality-of-perfect-spaces-with-the-countable-chain-condition) of mine. However, none of those examples is Lindelof, as they all contain large closed discrete subsets. This motivates the following question:

> QUESTION: Let $\kappa$ be any cardinal. Is there a Lindelof regular ccc space such that $c(X_\delta) > \kappa$?

To find a consistent example of a Lindelof ccc regular space such that $c(X_\delta) > 2^{\aleph_0}$ it suffices to take a small modification of Gorelic's example of a Lindelof space with points $G_\delta$ and cardinality larger than the continuum (see the remark at the beginning of page 606 of [Gorelic's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1993-118-02/S0002-9939-1993-1132417-0/S0002-9939-1993-1132417-0.pdf)).

A related Mathoverflow question is: [Covering compact Hausdorff spaces with closed $G_\delta$ sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322387/covering-compact-hausdorff-spaces-with-closed-g-delta-sets?rq=1)